# HTML <a> download Attribute works when opened in html but not when I run it on main.py

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, download

On a flask site, link to download pdf is provided on the page.

When i run the site by **main.py** i get the file doesn't exist error as given under,

but it works fine when i run only **index.html** file

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6kX.png)

in main.py

```
class ThePage(MethodView):

    def get(self):
        form = InfoForm()
        return render_template("index.html")
```

in index.html

```
    <a href="../1668671114.892154.pdf" download>
            <div class="btn-block2">
                <span class="hazir">&#9989;</span> <span style="font-size: 20px">PDF ready, click.</span>
            </div>
    </a>
```

Problem may be related to render_template part where i should add some arguments, though i couldn't figure out how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using a relative path to the templates directory. The server cannot resolve this URL. Use the `static` folder to deliver static files.

- Move the pdf file to a folder called `static` within your application's root directory.
- Inside the anchor tag use `url_for('static', filename='1668671114.892154.pdf')`

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='1668671114.892154.pdf') }}" download>
    <div class="btn-block2">
        <span class="hazir">&#9989;</span> <span style="font-size: 20px">PDF ready, click.</span>
    </div>
</a>
```